# Github URL to create new file with specific name?

Tags: github

I know you can use the URL `github.com/<username>/<project_name>/new/<branch_name>/<path_to_create_file>` to create a new file at a given path of a project.

Is there a way to do the same but from the URL specify the name of the new file?

So hitting something like the below in the browser:

```
http://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool/new/master/tests/newtest.py
```

Would get me to Github's online editor and I would be able to start typing for `newtest.py`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answer: Yes.**

You can set the parameter `filename` in the URL. You can even add some content to the new file. For instance, to create a new file called `newtest.py` with default value `PUT YOUR CODE HERE`, use the following URL:

https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool/new/master/tests?filename=newfile.py&value=PUT%20YOUR%20CODE%20HERE

Comment: I've also noticed you can pass "message" to set the commit message and "description" to set the commit summary. Are there any other parameters that can be used on the new file page?

Comment: So I've notice a problem with this: The commit button will be greyed out unless you make a change to the file contents, which isn't always necessary if the file contents are generated entirely automatically. Is there a flag to perhaps make github think the file contents have changed?