# "Commit New File" Disabled when Making New File Via URL in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm using the following approach to create new files on GitHub: "[Github URL to create new file with specific name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778095/github-url-to-create-new-file-with-specific-name)"

You can set the contents of the new file by setting the `value` URL parameter. However, GitHub refuses to let one commit the file unless the user makes at least one edit to the file contents; in my case the user won't need to edit the file most of the time. Is there a URL parameter I can pass that tells GitHub to make the "commit new file" button active without needing to edit its contents?

Example: `https://github.com/astrocatalogs/sne-internal/new/master/?filename=SN2012fz.json&value=%23%23%23%20DELETE%20THIS%20LINE%20TO%20ENABLE%20COMMIT%20BUTTON%20%23%23%23%0A%7B%0A%09%22SN2012fz%22%3A%7B%0A%09%09%22name%22%3A%22SN2012fz%22%2C%0A%09%09%22aliases%22%3A%5B%0A%09%09%09%22SN2012fz%22%2C%20%22SSS120707%3A200325-555719%22%0A%09%09%5D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D&message=Events%20SN2012fz%20and%20SSS120707:200325-555719%20marked%20as%20being%20the%20same%20via%20OSC%20duplicate%20finder.`

(I had to add a "delete this line to enable commit button" to let the user know how to activate the commit button after loading the page)

Comment: Can't believe this is *still* an issue in 2021!