# Replace GitHub URL interface with GitHub API

Tags: git, github

I currently run a website where users can click an edit link that automatically takes them to the GitHub webpage. Currently, you can pass parameters through the GitHub URL via GET like so:

```
github.com/<username>/<project_name>/new/<branch_name>/<path_to_create_file>?
    filename=<my_filename>&message=<my_message>
```

...and you are nicely taken to the new file GUI on the GitHub webpage.

Unfortunately, this approach seems to be very inflexible; you cannot specify things like "use existing branch if user has one already" or "allow commits without modification." The GitHub API appears to be a lot more powerful, but I am not sure how you can use it to get the nice GUI interface like you can with URLs. Is there a way to use the GitHub API in this way?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you're asking if you can use the API to generate a URL that a user can click to bring them to a GitHub page, then no I don't think that's possible (but I could certainly be wrong). Take a look at the documentation to see what's available: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: OK, that's unfortunate. If there were a more-complete URL schema out there (the only information appears to be this stackoverflow q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778095/github-url-to-create-new-file-with-specific-name), that could solve the issue too. The GitHub interface is so nice that it would be a shame to have to recreate your own file editor on your own page and submit the changes via the API to do even slightly more-complicated edits.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried a quick google search for "github url tricks" but only found a few things - not a complete documentation. Maybe someone else will know how to do this with the API.